# Usage of か before を

Tags: particle-か

During my immersion I bumped into this sentence その動作・作用が、どんな場所・場面において行われるかを表わす。
In 場面において行われるかを表わす。what is the role of か specifically?

Comment: It forms an 'embedded question'. Try searching this site for that tag.